# Are there any general listeners defined in Android or Java

Tags: java, android

Sometimes I want a simple generic Listener without defining my own class. Is there a predefined "something happened and here is a string or object or whatever" in Java or Android?

Comment: Basically, this is all I want. Does it exist?

    public interface SomethingHappenedListener {
  public void itHappened(Object object);
 }

Comment: MVC model, Observer, Observable shall do what you need

Comment: This is exactly what I want.  So sad that neither java or android have native support for events/delegation like c#, obj-c, swift, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A project I've worked on had that.  It lead to some frightfully unreadable and unmaintainable code once a class implemented the "MyListener" interface to handle two completely different kind of events.  There was a lack of separation of concerns, and you had no idea when or how that method might be invoked.

```
public interface GenericListener {
    public void handleMyEvent(Object sourceObj, int eventCode);
}

//...later on there's some implementation
public void handleMyEvent(Object sourceObj, int eventCode) {
    if ( sourceObj == startDownloadButton && eventCode == MyButton.CLICKED ) {
        //... 20 lines of code to start download
    } else if ( sourceObj instanceOf DownloadStatus && eventCode == DownloadStatus.COMPLETE ) {
        //... 10 lines of code to display status
    } else //... and on and on...
}
```

This isn't the kind of code duplication you need to avoid.  Just because two methods/interfaces share the same basic signature doesn't mean they should be combined into one.  I suggest you create listener interfaces that are completely self-documenting with regards to when and how they are used.

Answer (score 2):

There's java.util.Observer, but that only works for Observable subclasses. (That is, anything can implement the Observer interface, but it can only observe Observable objects.)

Comment: It's the only default generic event mechanism you can use in JDK, but your code will not be as meaningfull as when you use your own event system.

Comment: As far as I remember thet are implemented as classes, not interfaces. It also creates problem, when your class already has parent

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid defining a listener class, consider defining callback methods directly in the observable:

```
abstract class MyWorker{

    public MyWorker(){
        //...    
        onComplete(); 
    }

    protected abstract void onComplete();

}
```

Then override them later:

```
new MyWorker(){

    protected void onComplete(){
        //..
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is not suitable for every situation. Sometimes you need a real listener class.